# How to write a subclass statement in Prolog?

Tags: inheritance, prolog, subclass

Hello everyone this is my first time here :)!

I have the following Prolog set of definitions and the only one that isn't working is the Subclass. Can anyone help me out to figure out why this isn't :(

```
    % definitions of classes in our system 
    class(object). 
    class(animal). 
    class(cat). 
    class(dog). 
    class(dachshund). 
    class(toy). 
class(ball). 
class(post). 

% definitions of interfaces 
interface(iwoof). 
interface(imeow). 

% definitions of class inheritance 
inherits(animal,object). 
inherits(cat,animal). 
inherits(dog,animal). 
inherits(dachshund, dog). 
inherits(toy,object). 
inherits(ball,object). 
inherits(post,object). 
inherits(ball,toy).
inherits(post,toy).

% definitions of interface implementation 
implements(cat,imeow). 
implements(dog,iwoof). 

% definitions of objects (instances of classes) 
instance(fluffy,cat). 
instance(fido,dog). 
instance(rex,dog). 
instance(schnitzel,dachshund). 
instance(superscratch,post). 
instance(bouncyball,ball). 
instance(tennisball,ball). 

% definitions of behavior 
playswith(cat,post). 
playswith(dog,ball). 

% definitions of superclasses 
superclass(C,D) :- inherits(C,D). 
superclass(D,C) :- inherits(D,X), superclass(X,C). 

% definitions of subclasses 
subclass(C,D) :- superclass(X,D), inherits(C,X).
```

The output I need is

```
?- subclass(toy,X).
X = ball ;
X = post ;
false.
```

But I get

false.

Here is the trace.

```
?- trace, subclass(toy,X).
   Call: (7) subclass(toy, _G246) ? creep
   Call: (8) inherits(toy, _G366) ? creep
   Exit: (8) inherits(toy, object) ? creep
   Call: (8) superclass(object, _G246) ? creep
   Call: (9) inherits(object, _G246) ? creep
   Fail: (9) inherits(object, _G246) ? creep
   Redo: (8) superclass(object, _G246) ? creep
   Call: (9) inherits(object, _G366) ? creep
   Fail: (9) inherits(object, _G366) ? creep
   Fail: (8) superclass(object, _G246) ? creep
   Fail: (7) subclass(toy, _G246) ? creep
false.
```

Comment: In what way does it not work? Is there a reason why you switched the order of the arguments in `superclass/2` or is this an error?

Comment: If I were to type ?- subclass(toy,X). I would be expected to get this:
X = ball ;
X = post ;
false.
However I am only getting false.

Comment: It was how we were taught to do it. I've never done anything in Prolog before so i'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Have you tried doing `?- trace, subclass(toy,X).` to see where it goes wrong?

Comment: Fail: (9) inherits(object, _G246) ? creep
 Is the step

Comment: Add what you expect and what you get instead and this trace to the question, so that other can read it too! Read the guidelines on asking questions on StackOverflow, too, if you have the time.

Comment: I apologize, I will do that now.

Comment: @user2987775 the `inherits(object, _G246)` fails for obvious reasons, right? So you have to back up and see why that's being called with the first parameter instantiated as `object`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read your trace you will see your end problem: there is nothing that `object` inherits, or, there is no fact of the form `inherits(object, Anything).`. But this is probably not what you mean anyway!

To me it seems that just saying:

```
subclass(A, B) :-
    superclass(B, A).
```

should be enough in your case.

Comment: That did it... I feel so bad that it was that simple.. Thank you so much.

Comment: It is always simple, if you know where to look. This is why I point out the results of the trace.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative implementation in Logtalk (which you can run with most Prolog systems as the backend compiler) would be:

```
:- object(metaclass,
    imports(class_hierarchy),   % from the standard library
    instantiates(metaclass)).   % make metaclass its own metaclass

:- end_object.


:- object(object,
    instantiates(metaclass)).

:- end_object.


:- object(animal,
    instantiates(metaclass),
    specializes(object)).

    :- public(playswith/1).

:- end_object.


:- protocol(imeow).

    :- public(imeow/0).

:- end_protocol.


:- protocol(iwoof).

    :- public(iwoof/0).

:- end_protocol.


:- object(cat,
    implements(imeow),
    instantiates(metaclass),
    specializes(animal)).

    imeow.
    playswith(post). 

:- end_object.


:- object(dog,
    implements(iwoof),
    instantiates(metaclass),
    specializes(animal)).

    iwoof.
    playswith(ball).

:- end_object.


:- object(dachshund,
    instantiates(metaclass),
    specializes(dog)).

:- end_object.


:- object(toy,
    instantiates(metaclass),
    specializes(object)).

:- end_object.


:- object(ball,
    instantiates(metaclass),
    specializes(toy)).

:- end_object.


:- object(post,
    instantiates(metaclass),
    specializes(toy)).

:- end_object.


:- object(fluffy,
    instantiates(cat)).

:- end_object.


:- object(fido,
    instantiates(dog)).

:- end_object.


:- object(rex,
    instantiates(dog)).

:- end_object.


:- object(schnitzel,
    instantiates(dachshund)).

:- end_object.


:- object(superscratch,
    instantiates(post)).

:- end_object.


:- object(bouncyball,
    instantiates(ball)).

:- end_object.


:- object(tennisball,
    instantiates(ball)).

:- end_object.
```

Sample queries from your post:

```
?- toy::subclass(Subclass).
Subclass = ball ;
Subclass = post.
```

Of course, in this solution your task is mainly reduced to specifying the hierarchy and the interfaces. There's a learning reward in doing it by implementing inheritance yourself.

Comment: With SWI-Prolog on Windows 7 64 bits, I can load your code with logtalk_load(File). but I get this message  : 
` logtalk_load('C:/Users/Utilisateur/Documents/Logtalk/trav/first.lgt').
*     Reference to unknown category: class_hierarchy
*       in file c:/users/utilisateur/documents/logtalk/trav/first.lgt between lines 1-3
*       while compiling object metaclass
% [ c:/users/utilisateur/documents/logtalk/trav/first.lgt loaded ]
% 1 compilation warning `  ?- toy::subclass(Subclass).
ERROR: object `toy' does not exist

Comment: Sorry, I can't destroy my comment above, I made a mistake copying your code.

Comment: You also need first to load the used library entities by calling `logtalk_load(library(hierarchies_loader))`.